# i3 not showing on my login screen (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: gdm, i3-wm

I newly installed Ubuntu and later i3, it was working for a while but suddenly among other things i3 stopped working, the "other things" were fixed by simply reinstalling them or installing them (as they seemed to not be available somehow) e.g python poetry, but i3 wasn't one of them. I've reinstalled, uninstalled and installed it, and installed it with a different method than I used before but it's not showing up. I've restarted `gdm` but to no avail, my i3.desktop file looks okay, here it is:

```
Name=i3
Comment=improved dynamic tiling window manager
Exec=/usr/bin/i3
TryExec=i3
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=i3
DesktopNames=i3
Keywords=tiling;wm;windowmanager;window;manager;
```

I've tried a lot of methods from this platform that I don't remember like the one @vanadium suggested but it didn't work. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I later solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling gdm3 with these commands `sudo apt-get remove gdm3`, `sudo apt-get install gdm3`,
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`,
`sudo systemctl restart gdm` and now it works.